# what is the resolve 'function' in the promise settimeout best practice?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

While learning about async in javascript I came across this best practice for a sleep() function in javascript.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235#39914235)

In the w3school documentation for `setTimeout`, it says the first parameter must be a function that will be called when the timer resolves. So if resolve is a function, is it just skipped because its never implemented?

What exactly is going on here? I'm a little dyslexic so sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both the same.

The first example you provided, if written in full, would look like this:

function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
return setTimeout(resolve, ms)
});
}

(note: this is your first function, not your second - although they are essentially the same I'd like to emphasize that this is a rewrite of your first function)

That is, you are passing the anonymous function:

```
(resolve) => {
  return setTimeout(resolve, ms)
}
```

to the `Promise`. However, the syntax of arrow functions allow some shortcuts.

The first shortcut is that if the function has just one statement you can omit the `{}`. That is to say the function above can be written in shorthand as:

```
(resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,ms);
```

So

```
(resolve) => {
  return setTimeout(resolve, ms)
}
```

and

```
(resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,ms);
```

is exactly the same function but the second version is written in shorthand.

Another shortcut is that if a function accepts only one argument you can remove the `()` around the arguments. So the function above can be rewritten as:

```
resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms);
```

Note this is exactly the same as:

```
(resolve) => {
  return setTimeout(resolve, ms)
}
```

only written in shorthand.

---

### Additional answer.

You asked

> So if resolve is a function, is it just skipped because its never implemented?

You are mistaken. It is not never implemented. It is implemented by the person who wrote the `Promise` class.

Here's what the `Promise` class does:

If you call me as a constructor then you need to pass a function with two arguments to me. I will call your function later with two arguments, both functions, that you may call. If you call the first function then I will assume you are OK. If you call the second function then I will assume there was an error.

That's all there is to it. The two arguments (usually called `resolve` and `reject` but you can name them anything) are defined by the `Promise` class and will be passed to your function when the `Promise` class calls your function.

Here's an example implementation of my own `Promise` class to demonstrate what's going on:

```
// Warning. For illustration purposes only. This class does not
// fully implement the Promise design pattern as specified by ECMA262:

class Promise {
    constructor (yourfunction) {
        this.result = undefined;
        this.error = undefined;

        function resolve (x) {this.result = x};
        function reject (y) {this.error = y};

        yourfunction(resolve,reject); // calling your function!!
    }

    then (yourcallback) {
        yourcallback(this.result);
    }

    catch (yourcallback) {
        if (this.error) yourcallback(this.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. The additional answer is what I was looking for. I must have missed it while reading the documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses around the parameter list of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a single parameter are optional. The two syntaxes are exactly equivalent:

```
resolve => …
(resolve) => …
```

Which one you use is a style preference, and not a matter of best practice.

Arrow function parameter lists with more than one parameter always need parentheses.

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

add(1, 2)
// returns 3
```

The parentheses don’t denote a function call, just like `(ms)` isn’t a function call in `function sleep(ms)`.

Comment: Ah I see, but that still doesn't answer my question, I will edit my question for clarity

Comment: @Sujio: `resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)` is a function. It’s like `function startSomePromiseWork(resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, ms); }` followed by `return new Promise(startSomePromiseWork);`.